# Why am I getting values that are outside of my rand function parameters?

Tags: c++, random

I am trying to output 25 random values between 3 and 7 using a function. Every time I run my program, I receive two values that are within those parameters, but the rest are out of range.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

void showArray(int a[], int size);

void showArray(int a[], const int size)
{ 
    int i;
    
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << a[i] << ", ";
    }
}
 

int main()
{
    //int iseed = time(NULL);
    //srand(iseed);

    srand(time(NULL));
    int randomNumb = rand() % 3 + 4;
    int array[]  = {randomNumb};

    showArray(array, 25);
}
```

This is my Output:

> 4, 4, -300313232, 32766, 540229437, 32767, 0, 0, 1, 0, -300312808, 32766, 0, 0, -300312761, 32766, -300312743, 32766, -300312701, 32766, -300312679, 32766, -300312658, 32766, -300312287,

Comment: With `int array[]  = {randomNumb};`, how many elements are in the array?  How big is the array?  Answering those should help you figure out why you have weird numbers

Comment: In your own words, if you want to output 25 random values, how many times do you need to choose a random value? In your own words, how many times do you think your current code chooses a random value? Why? How?

Comment: In your own words, when you write `int array[]  = {randomNumb};`, how many elements do you expect `array` to contain? Why? How did you specify the number of elements? If you try to output 25 values from that array, do you see why that causes a problem?

Comment: Note that as random as it  may look, reading outside the bounds of an object is NOT a good random number generator.

Comment: Thanks, it all makes sense now  

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `rand()` only 1 time, and storing the result in `randomNumb`, which is a single integer.

Your array is being created with only 1 element in it - the value of `randomNumb`.  But, you are telling `showArray()` that the array has 25 elements, which it doesn't.  So, `showArray()` is going out of bounds of the array and displaying random garbage from surrounding memory.  Which is **undefined behavior**.

If you want 25 random numbers, then you need to allocate an array that can hold 25 numbers, and then call `rand()` 25 times to fill that array, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void showArray(int a[], const int size)
{ 
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        cout << a[i] << ", ";
    }
}
 
int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    int array[25];
    for(int i = 0; i < 25; ++i)
        array[i] = rand() % 3 + 4;

    showArray(array, 25);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation ! 